# У ValueAnimator бесконечный вызов cancel(), если вызывать его из слушателя

Tags: android, анимация, ui, listener

Есть два экземпляра `ValueAnimator`, сторнуемые через onClickListener - один двигает `view` вверх, другой ту же `view` вниз. У каждого есть `startListener`, чтоб когда стартует один, у второго вызывался `cancel()`.

То есть если анимацию, допустим вверх, прервать посередине, - вызвать анимацию вниз, то должен сработать `cancel()`, и он срабатывает, но если на обе анимации поставить `startOffset`, то `cancel()` в `startListener`-e  срабатывает много раз(как в цикле),а затем `stackOverFlowError`.

Заметил, что та же ошибка будет и без `startOffset`-ов,  но если вызвать оба старта на одну `view` без вызова `cancel()`, но в `startListener`-e -то `саncel()` вызывается(!) и что `startListener` срабатывает не при вызове у анимации `start`,а с учетом `startOffset`.

А теперь все в коде:

```
Float firstLevelUp = 200f;
Float firstLevelDown = 0f;

long duration = 1500l;

ValueAnimator valueAnimatorView1Down = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(firstLevelUp,firstLevelDown);
ValueAnimator valueAnimatorView1Up = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(firstLevelUp,firstLevelDown);


public void initAnim(final View view){
    valueAnimatorView1Down.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimatorView1Up.setDuration(duration);

    valueAnimatorView1Down.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            if (valueAnimatorView1Up.isStarted()) {
                valueAnimatorView1Up.cancel();
                valueAnimatorView1Down.setCurrentPlayTime(duration - valueAnimatorView1Up.getCurrentPlayTime());
                Log.i("Down View1 animation " , "STARTED WITH CANCEL");
            }else {
                Log.i("Down View1 animation " , "STARTED WITHOUT CANCEL");
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Log.i("DownView1 animation " , "CANCELED");
        }
    });

    valueAnimatorView1Up.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            
            if (valueAnimatorView1Down.isStarted()) {
                valueAnimatorView1Down.cancel();
                valueAnimatorView1Up.setCurrentPlayTime(duration - valueAnimatorView1Down.getCurrentPlayTime());
                Log.i("Up View1 animation " , "STARTED WITH CANCEL");
            }else {
                Log.i("Up View1 animation " , "STARTED WITHOUT CANCEL");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Log.i("Up View1 animation " , "CANCELED");
        }
    });

//здесь updateListener-ы с типичными
//view.setTranslationY((Float) [animation].getAnimatedValue());
   
public void startViewAnimation(boolean side) {

    if (side) {
        Log.i("Down animations ", "start()");
        valueAnimatorView1Down.setStartDelay(800);
        valueAnimatorView1Down.start();


    } else {
        Log.i("Up animations ", "start()");
        valueAnimatorView1Up.setStartDelay(800);
        valueAnimatorView1Up.start();
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

- Почему `сancel()` в `onStartListener`-е вызывается много раз + `stackOverFlowError`, если сменить анимацию на вторую,до того как в первой закончился `startOffset`? (хотя если вызвать новую анимацию после отсрочки старта - все работает корректно)
- Как исправить?